# Mac App Store Download Resume

Tags: mac, osx-lion, mac-app-store

I'm using Mac App Store on Lion, But there is a problem with download resume. After every system restart I can't resume my previous downloads and I have to download them from the beginning, I also checked and I have no AppStore directory at this path ~/Library/Application Support/
I'm wondering if anyone have a solution for this issue.

Regards

Comment: I don't have an AppStore directory in Application Support, either (and everything works fine). What makes you assume that there should be such a directory?